# User images slideshow: first slide from reference entity

Tags: 7, views, theming

I wish to do a slideshow with a first slide of my node picture and then others slides with pictures submitted by users (affiliated to a node via entity reference).

What I want to do is (Node Entity Reference Image) (userA pic1) (userA pic2) (userA pic3) (userB pic3).

I edited a view template

```
  <div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">content(image) goes here</div></div>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $key => $row): ?>
      <div class="item">
        <?php print $row ?>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </div>
```

How can I output my "field_passager_image" defined by relationship to Content entity referenced from "field_passager_id" passed through an url argument (node id from url) ?

[image: View Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1569422) using [view field views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) by putting my user entity field view inside my node entity view.